# insert numbers into table using pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

I'm trying to insert a range of numbers into a SQL Server Database using the `executemany` function. My input is going to be a list of numbers ranging from a few hundred to maybe 10k rows.

```py
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
sql = 'CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#numbers] ([number] int not null)'

cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.commit()

sql = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[#numbers] (number) values (?)'

l = list(range(1, 10))
cursor.executemany(sql,l)
```

```
TypeError: ('Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000')
```

I'm guessing I need to convert my list of ints to a list of lists or tuples which is what I really seem to be struggling with.

Comment: Try to delete the `(number)` in the sql insert command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just like the error says: params should be in a list, tuple or Row.

You're trying to insert `1, 2, 3, 4, ...`, which is a list of **single** values.

What you want is to insert a **list** of values for each row, which means something like:

`[[1], [2], [3], [4], ...]`

So, if you change your `l` to:

`l = [[i] for i in range(1, 10)]`

then it should work.

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks. Was trying to convert the ints to a list with ```l = list(list(i) for i in range(1, 10))``` for which int was not iterable